# get_post_meta doesnt work after moving wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, post, get, meta

I have this small piece of code that doesn't work when i MOVE a WordPress website to another location, (IT DOES WORK ON THE ORIGINAL LOCATION):

```
function displayCustomFields() {
global $post; 
$rt_gallery_images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "rtthemert_gallery_images");
var_dump ($rt_gallery_images);
}
```

var_dump displays:

```
array( 0 => boolean false )
```

But if I remove the meta_value like the following code :

```
function displayCustomFields() {
global $post; 
$rt_gallery_images = get_post_meta( $post->ID);                 
var_dump ($rt_gallery_images);
}
```

the var_dump shows:

```
'rtthemert_gallery_images' => array
      0 => string 'a:1:{i:0;s:72:"/ssold/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/picture-3.jpg";}' (length=81)
```

and the rest of the meta values

I have exactly the same code in both location, why it works on the original and not on the copy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what was the problem, the db has been migrated and some serialized data has been mistakenly edited. I was able to solve this by running the code on the following page:
http://alexscammon.com/2011/06/migrating-wordpress-blogs-fixing-the-serialization/